# Tornado and Django limitations?

Tags: django, fastcgi, wsgi, tornado

here is what i've found when reading Tornado Help:

> Tornado comes with limited support for WSGI. However, since WSGI does not support non-blocking requests, you cannot use any of the asynchronous/non-blocking features of Tornado in your application if you choose to use WSGI instead of Tornado’s HTTP server. Some of the features that are not available in WSGI applications: @tornado.web.asynchronous, the httpclient module, and the auth module.

what it was interresting "before" reading that is the "***auth***" module, it will make possible to access to Facebook or Google, it's like OpenID (?), but sadly it will not work on WSGI?!!! so how to make that thing work with Django? on FastCGI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at mixins in tornado.auth module you will see that it requires @asynchronous decorator, which is unavailable in WSGI mode due to synchronous nature of the protocol.

There was some kind of proposition to add asynchronous support to WSGI, but I believe it was not successful. Additional info on this:

http://mail.python.org/pipermail/web-sig/2008-May/003439.html

http://mail.python.org/pipermail/web-sig/2008-July/003545.html

Comment: so the WSGI is from the beginning not made for asynchronous, no neither Django, nor Flask can do it :(

Comment: @abdel Tornado itself can provide all basic tools neccessary for creating any kind of web application, so generally you do not actually need any other framework or protocol to make it up and running.

Comment: @abdel actually that WSGI support was added mostly to make it easier to migrate legacy applications from some other framework (like Django and many others) to pure tornado...

Comment: but the problem is about documentation?! django has tons of books, flask has an excellent all-in-one online help, but tornado, i've checked, from their website, it seems that they're talking to professional (very) guys :(